# Is it a bad practice for a Spring Components library vendor to allow Java packages to be autoscanned by consumers instead of JavaConfig?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I developed a library (Servlet Filter which adds metrics for HTTP requests) and I want to distribute it among the teams at our company. Which way is preferable for them to use it? They can either use explicit Java @Beans definitions or autoscan the package.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, WebApdexMetricsFilter.class})
public class Application {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot for all dependent applications then the preferable way is to create autoconfiguration class within your library that will be picked up by application context as soon as your library is included into runtime classpath of an application.

If you don't want to make your library dependent on Spring Boot annotations then in your library you can create configuration class (anyway you depend on Spring as soon as you have stereotype annotations over classes of your lib)

```
@Configuration
public class MyLibConfig {
  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    return new MyBeanImpl();
  }
}
```

and in dependent app just include it with `@Import(MyLibConfig.class)`.

If your library doesn't depend on Spring, then use explicit `@Bean` declaration, this would work faster as Spring won't scan all the packages of your lib.